# Java pattern matcher group definition

Tags: java, regex

I have a simple regular expression which looks something like

```
([a-z]*)( +[a-z]="[0-9]")*
```

and it works in matching patterns like

```
test a="1" b="2" c="3"...
```

Is there any way of capturing each of the name-value pairs (e.g., a="1") in a separate matcher group?

As it is in the above example, I get a matcher group for (test) and only one matcher group for the 3 name-value pairs (i.e., the last one, c="3"). I would expect 3 matcher groups, 1 for each such pair.

Comment: Regex are good at finding serial killers on vacation, but they aren't good for everything. If you have a data protocol, perhaps you should consider sequential processing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would expect 3 matcher groups, 1 for each such pair.

No, it's two groups in total. The only way to get the key-value pairs in three groups, is by doing:

```
([a-z]*)( +[a-z]="[0-9]")( +[a-z]="[0-9]")( +[a-z]="[0-9]")
```

You could match *all* key value pairs in a single group and then use a separate Pattern & Matcher on it:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String text = "test a=\"1\" b=\"2\" c=\"3\" bar d=\"4\" e=\"5\"";
    System.out.println(text + "\n");

    Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile("([a-z]*)((?:[ \t]+[a-z]=\"[0-9]\")*)").matcher(text);

    while(m1.find()) {

      System.out.println(m1.group(1));

      Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("([a-z])=\"([0-9])\"").matcher(m1.group(2));

      while (m2.find()) {
        System.out.println("  " + m2.group(1) + " -> " + m2.group(2));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which produces:

```
test a="1" b="2" c="3" bar d="4" e="5"

test
  a -> 1
  b -> 2
  c -> 3

bar
  d -> 4
  e -> 5
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `Matcher#find()` method to switch to the next group.

Do it in a loop, like:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
while (matcher.find()) {
    //extract groups here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of. But if you match `\s+\w="\d"`, then you can call `find` multiple times and process each match on its own.