# Java regex to find a method's arguments

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find a regex to split a call to a method

```
boo(a,b), c
```

so it would return

```
boo(a,b)
```

and

```
c
```

after splitting by it.
Is it possible doing it with regex?
Thanks.

Comment: Just find `),` and before that is the method and after is the extra stuff?

Comment: Are you looking at plaintext, the `.class` file, or are you reading it in?

Comment: the problem is that it has to be recursive. i.e
boo(a(a,b),b),c should split by the "," before the c, only find the "highest level" ','s
The String is read from a file, manipulated and is in a String object

Comment: Instead RegEx you should try parsing it through a ``Stack``.

Comment: @Lablabla If that's the case, you should probably edit your post because you did not mention anything of this sort. Also, how would you ever get a method call to look like that in the first place?

Comment: Visit [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(data_structure)?) for reference.

Comment: You have a similar post here that may answer you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324542/java-pattern-matcher-group-definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular languages cannot express recursion.  At the point where you realise that the solution would involve recursion, it is not possible to express this in a "pure" regex engine (in practice, most regex engines have some sort of extension to allow limited violation of this rule).

Since you're writing in a Java context - why not use the nice *programming language* to perform this fairly simple manipulation of a string, rather than trying to [shoehorn](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247#comment-3085) a regex into the solution? :)

Comment: +1, for this clear approach. May or may not be it to be done in RegEx is another matter.

Comment: it's a about regexes. we could use other methods, however since the homework are all about regexes, if it's possible, I'd rather do it this way

Comment: Fair enough (though I think the question would be better if you emphasize that you're specifically thinking about regexes for educational purposes, instead of merely thinking it's a practical way to solve this problem).  Though I stand by my answer - *strictly* you can't do it with regexes, but I'm sure Java's regex engine has something in to cope with this.  I leave it to others to point out what that might be!  Maybe "no" really is the correct answer in the context of this homework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you really regarding your question want but with the given case :

```
"boo(a,b), c".split("(?<=\\)),") //look for a ',' preceeded by ')'
```

gives you an array containing `["boo(a,b)","c"]`.

EDIT :

For this case : **boo(a(a,b),b),c**, use :

```
"boo(a(a,b),b),c".split("(?<=\\)),(?!(\\w\\p{Punct}?)+\\))")
```

`(?!(\\w\\p{Punct}?)+\\))` means you don't accept match if it's followed by **(a word and one or zero punctuation) *n times***,  and **a right parenthesis**.

The result is an array containing `["boo(a(a,b),b)","c"]`.